# Passing an equation as a parameter in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
newnooftimes = nooftimes + 1;
if (nooftimes < 10) {
    setTimeout("roll(newnooftimes);", 150);
}
```

vs

```
if (nooftimes < 10) {
    setTimeout("roll(nooftimes + 1);", 150);
}
```

Why doesn't the latter work, even though the former works?

EDIT: This is my entire function. Seems like there might be some issue with variables running out of scope? I'm new to javascript so would appreciate some help to point me to what went wrong. This function is using the suggested code in the reply before, but it still doesn't work. roll() is only called once, by another call outside the function. The recursion never happens - why?

```
function roll(nooftimes) {
    ctx.clearRect(dicex,dicey,diceWidth,diceHeight); //clears the space where the dice face may have been already drawn
    var roll = 1+Math.floor(Math.random()*6);
    drawFace(roll); 
    if (nooftimes < 10) {
        setTimeout(function () { roll(nooftimes + 1); }, 150);
    }
}
```

Comment: Both work for me in Chrome 23: http://jsfiddle.net/L4qqR/ Although you should use closure in this case.

Comment: @K L: What does your script console say? Explain "does not work".

Comment: Please, please, please DON'T pass a string to `setTimeout()`.  That can often create scoping issues which may or may not be the problem here (we have no way of knowing without seeing the rest of your code).  Instead, pass a function refererence.

Comment: What do you mean by script console @Cthulhu? I'm quite new to web dev - using firebug in firefox but it doesn't say anything?

Comment: I edited to show more of my code, any help would be appreciated. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it in a lambda. You should pass a function to it, not a function call. Though browsers often try to figure out your intentions, so sometimes some sketchy things work.

```
if (nooftimes < 10) {
    setTimeout(function () { roll(nooftimes + 1); }, 150);
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it still doesn't work. Could you look at my code in my original post? Thanks

Comment: When you redeclare roll inside the `roll` function, the `roll` inside lambda binds to the local roll (let me test) instead of the function. Here's my simplified jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Q5D3F/ - which shows the mechanism works

Comment: Thanks, that's something I overlooked!

Comment: Glad I could help. Always the little things, darn annoying when they take so long to find xD